# How to make a python command executed via Jupyter.kernel.execute command visible in an Input Cell in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, kernel, execute, jupyter

I can execute a python command from Javascript side via Jupyter.kernel.execute(command). For example the command may be something like "a = 3". I can see a new variable named "a" is set to 3, that is OK.

I would like to have this command echoed in the INPUT CELL, as if it is entered manually. Is it possible, how can it be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A very simple example would be (paste the code below in a notebook cell):

```
%%javascript

// Function that accepts a string of code
var create_and_execute_cell_below = function (code){
    var nb = Jupyter.notebook

    // create cell below this one
    nb.insert_cell_below()

    // select cell below (the one we have created)
    var cell = nb.select_next().get_selected_cell()

    // set text in the cell
    cell.set_text(code)

    // execute cell
    cell.execute()
}

// run the function created above with code 'k = 1'
// and it will create a new cell, filled with 'k = 1'
// and it will execute that cell.
// if you run this cell using [ctrl] + [enter] only one cell
// will be created.
// if you run this cell using [Shift] + [enter] two cells
// will be created, the one of the [Shift] + [enter] command
// and the one of the function created above with the code.
create_and_execute_cell_below('k = 1')
```

I hope it helps.

OTOH, [the front-end API could be not very stable and there is a lack of documentation](http://jupyter-notebook.readthedocs.io/en/latest/frontend_config.html#configuring-the-notebook-frontend) and some stuff could change and maybe the code posted above is not the best way to do what you need.

Comment: At the moment it works great. Neat and clean. You do not use kernel.execute, at least explicitely. cell.execute may be using it implicitely. The magic is creating and selecting the next cell. Otherwise it works but does not show up. Thanks.